# Accessing Old reddit posts

Tags: csv, reddit

I grabbed a set of data attributes of reddit articles into a csv using a php script, after grabbing those posts I need to monitor each article' status hourly for the next 24 hours. I have the attributes Title, ID, Name, No of comments, and Domain, but I'm currently unable to find a way to access the each/corresponding reddit post using just those attributes.

[image: The csv which I have data]

Can anybody tell me a way to access each reddit post in this csv using any of the data in its columns?

Comment: any reddit expert out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` field is used in the post URL, like this: `92dd8` becomes [`https://www.reddit.com/comments/92dd8`](https://www.reddit.com/comments/92dd8), which is equivalent to [`https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/92dd8/test_post_please_ignore`](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/92dd8/test_post_please_ignore) (except that the subreddit style is missing).

You can also use `/api/info` with the `name` field: `t3_92dd8` becomes [`https://www.reddit.com/api/info?id=t3_92dd8`](https://www.reddit.com/api/info?id=t3_92dd8) (if you want it as JSON you can do [`https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=t3_92dd8`](https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?id=t3_92dd8), which is the intended use of `/api/info` but it still works for HTML viewing).  Note that `/api/info` only gives information about the link, and not comments on it, but it's still useful.  (Also, `/api/info` can take up to 100 posts by combining them with a comma: [`https://www.reddit.com/api/info?id=t3_92dd8,t3_2np694`](https://www.reddit.com/api/info?id=t3_92dd8,t3_2np694) - this may be useful if you want to query a bunch of posts at once).